# In R, how to define directly all columns of a dataframe with some columns depending on others?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to define a dataframe in the most lisible way. The problem arise when the defintion of some columns depends on others. I hoped that the following example would work:

```
myda3 <- data.frame(
  a3 = runif(10),
  b3 = 2*a3,
  c3 = a3 + b3)
```

but it doesn't:

```
Error in data.frame(a3 = runif(10), b3 = 2 * a3, c3 = a3 + b3) : object 'a3' not found
```

I know I can do either of these:

```
myda1 <- data.frame (a1=runif(10))
myda1$b1 <- 2*myda1$a1
myda1$c1 <- myda1$a1 + myda1$b1

a2 <- runif(10)
b2 <- 2*a2
c2 <- a2 + b2
myda2 <- data.frame(a2, b2,c2)
```

but they are harder to read (and the latter creates unecessary and potentailly dangerous elements)

Comment: Try `tibble`. See : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html

Comment: Thank you Rohit. I was reluctant to switch to tibble as old code writen for dataframes may not behave as expected with tibble, but `tibble` just scored a point here !